# why does my program not approximate pi?

Tags: c++, math, random, probability, montecarlo

I'm trying to write a program that approximates pi by using the probability that two random numbers are coprime which is 6/pi^2 so i should be able to aproximate pi as sqrt(6/probability) but for some reason it doesn't tend towards pi rather it seems to tend towards 3.912. i have tried the rand() function and i have tried the mersenne twister random number generator but they both give me similar results. what's going on? here is my code in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int times;

    cout << "enter number of times: ";
    cin >> times;

    for(int i = 0; i <= times; i ++)
    {
        double pi_approx, probability;
        int num1, num2, number_of_coprime;
        num1 = rand();
        num2 = rand();
        if(__gcd(num1, num2)>1)
        {
           number_of_coprime++;
        }

        probability = double(number_of_coprime)/double(i);
        pi_approx = sqrt(6/probability);

        cout <<100*i/times<< "% number of coprimes: "<< number_of_coprime << " pi approximation: " << pi_approx<<endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `number_of_coprime` is uninitialized and defined in the wrong scope.

Comment: And that loop will run `times+1` times.

Comment: Aren't the numbers coprime `if(__gcd(num1, num2)==1)`?

Comment: You should really turn on warnings... For new project, `-Wall -Wextra` is sensible for *gcc* and *clang*, `/W:4` for Visual C.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare variables in a proper scope, and the right formula is that probability goes to 6/pi^2 as number of times goes to infinity. Try the following code:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    //for (int times = 100; times < 1000; ++times) 
    int times = 1000000;
    {
        double pi_approx, probability;
        int number_of_coprime = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            int num1, num2;
            num1 = rand() % times;
            num2 = rand() % times;
            if (__gcd(num1, num2) == 1) // increment if coprime !!
            {
                number_of_coprime++;
            }
        }
        probability = double(number_of_coprime) / double(times);
        pi_approx = sqrt(6 / probability);
        cout << pi_approx << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> 3.14179

Comment: You broke the original's code behavior, the only variable that was in the wrong scope (and uninitialized) was `number_of_coprime`. The question wasn't "why is my code terrible, please fix it", but rather "why am I getting 3.912 and not 3.141"

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the wrong thing: you should increment the counter when they are coprime (gcd == 1), but you increment when the gcd is > 1.

Comment: In other words: here is pi, using the value you computed: math.sqrt(6/(1-6/(3.912*3.912)))

Comment: Even though his code is terrible and should be burnt at stake, this is the actual correct answer and not the other answer that also tries to fix the code and breaks the original behavior.